# How to capture a group in a sed that uses bash variables

Tags: bash, sed

I am using sed with variables in a bash script to parse markdown images `![Legend](path/image.png)`, and I am trying to capture a group of caracters in the same time.

The syntax for a "normal" regex would be like this to capture 1. the image legend, 2. the image path : `!\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)`

For instance from `![[Muybridge, Eadward](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Eadweard-Muybridge/images-videos)(1887)](https://i.imgur.com/p2pwfme.jpg)` would gives :

1. legend : `[Muybridge, Eadward](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Eadweard-Muybridge/images-videos)(1887)`
2. path : `https://i.imgur.com/p2pwfme.jpg`

But the normal regex complexifies within the sed using a variable.

Here is the piece of the scripts that parses the images in a markdown document (my question addresses the last sed command):

```sh
for filename in "$3"*; do
  COUNTER=$[$COUNTER +1]
  echo "<b>${filename%.*}</b> will be renamed <b>${GET[id]}-img${COUNTER}.*</b><br>"
  sed -i -e "s@${filename%.*}@${GET[id]}\-img${COUNTER}@g" ../${GET[id]}.md
  mv ${filename%.*}.${filename##*.} ${GET[id]}-img${COUNTER}.${filename##*.}
  sed -i -e "s@!['('.*')'](.*${GET[id]}\-img${COUNTER}@![\1](media\/${GET[id]}\-img${COUNTER}@g" ../${GET[id]}.md
done
```

You will see that:

1. I use double quotes since sed calls variables
2. I use `@` seperator instead of `/`
3. I don't need to escape the `[` `]` in this context (this is confirmed)
4. I tried to escape the group capturing parentheses with `'('.*')'` but it doesn't work, also tried with `\(.*\)`

I am therefore wondering how to capture a group (which is how to correctly use `()` according to regex syntax) in such context : bash+sed+variables.

Comment: Why do you think you don't need to escape `[]` in this context? That's not correct.

Comment: Using `sed -i` this way...you might as well just rewrite the loop as `for filename in "$3"*; do rm -f "$filename"; done`

Comment: wrt `I use double quotes since sed calls variables` - don't do that as it exposes the whole command to the shell for interpretation, just open up the single quotes where necessary for the shortest section to allow the shell access to just the required variables, e.g. do `sed 's/foo'"$var"'bar//'`, not `sed "s/foo${var}bar//"`. I can't figure out what your question is about though - please clarify it and show a simple, minimal example of **the problem** if you'd like help.

Answer (score 0):

> You will see that:
>
> 1. I use double quotes since sed calls variables
> 2. I use `@` seperator instead of `/`
> 3. I don't need to escape the `[` `]` in this context (this is confirmed)
> 4. I tried to escape the group capturing parentheses with `'('.*')'` but it doesn't work, also tried with `\(.*\)`
>
> I am therefore wondering how to capture a group (which is how to correctly use () according to regex syntax) in such context : bash+sed+variables.

To adapt your regular expression (I mean, the one you called the "normal" regex) to sed within double quotes, try this:

```
sed "s@!\[\(.*\)]\((.*)\)@Captures: 1: \1 2: \2@"
```

Then, if you feed in the inputs you gave us, you should see:

```
Captures: 1: [Muybridge, Eadward](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Eadweard-Muybridge/images-videos)(1887) 2: (https://i.imgur.com/p2pwfme.jpg)
```

So that shows you how to escape the regex in general.

Notes:

- It is not correct that you don't need to escape `[` `]` in this context. You need to escape the first one, but not the second.
- In your code example, you refer to variables that are not defined, and patterns that don't match your sample inputs, so I can't help with that bit.